# Powershell: How to add null parameters in function call with Splatting

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a function call implemented using Splatting.

```
$funtioncall= @{                                   
      Param1=$Param1;
      Param2=$Param2;
      Param3=$Param3;
      Param4=$Param4;
      Param5=$Param5;
}
function @functioncall
```

On a certain scenario i wish to add two more optional Parameters to the function call only if they are not null.

So i have $OptionalParam1 and $OptionalParam2

I currently have the below code to enable splatting as it will not allow nulls to be included in the Hash Table!

```
if(($OptionalParam1)-and($OptionalParam2))
{
   $funtioncall= @{                                   
          Param1=$Param1;
          Param2=$Param2;
          Param3=$Param3;
          Param4=$Param4;
          Param5=$Param5;
          OptionalParam1=$OptionalParam1;
          OptionalParam2=$OptionalParam2;
                   }
}
else
{
   $funtioncall= @{                                   
          Param1=$Param1;
          Param2=$Param2;
          Param3=$Param3;
          Param4=$Param4;
          Param5=$Param5;
                  }
}
function @functioncall
```

**Is there a simpler way i can do this with Splatting?**

This without splatting would be easier to implement and function call would look like below,( as i can have the parameter defined in the function to allow null )

```
function -Param1 $Param1 -Param2 $Param2 -Param3 $Param3 -Param4 $Param4 -Param5 $Param5 -OptionalParam1 $OptionalParam1 -OptionalParam2 $OptionalParam2
```

Comment: Why does the splat with the optional parameters work for both cases? Or do you mean that doesn't pass them with `$null` and you need them passed with `$null` (instead of not passed at all)?

Comment: Yes, if it is $null i will not be able to use splat and so my function call is complicated with adding condition to check if the OptionalParams are not $null before including them in HashTable

Comment: That didn't answer my question. Why does it not work with them as `$null`? What happens if you do that that isn't what you want. Are they not passed at all (and is that different to the function then them being passed with a `$null` argument)?

Comment: can Hashtables hold null values!

Comment: Oh Yes, seems it can, i tried to add $null values to it! Invalid Question !!

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to change anything. `$null` is still a value so there is no reason to treat building of the variable `$funtioncall` differently at all

```
$param1 = "Awesome"
$OptionalParam1 = $null

$funtioncall= @{                                   
      Param1=$Param1;
      OptionalParam1=$OptionalParam1;
}
```

So now the hashtable contains a null for `OptionalParam1`

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                
OptionalParam1                                                                                                                                      
Param1                         Awesome
```

So as long as your function can handle to possibility of the param being null there will be no issue. I made a small function that displays those values.

```
This @funtioncall

Param1 is 'Awesome'
OptionalParam1 is ''
```

Comment: Why bother with the existence guard? Why not just always assign?

Comment: yeah... you are right. I was mostly trying to remove the redundant varialbe population

Answer (score 0):

Took me forever to find this, so even though this is an old post I thought I would share the answer.

```
 $MyParameters= @{                                   
      Param1=$Param1
      Param2=$Param2
      Param3=$Param3
      Param4=$Param4
      Param5=$Param5
 }

 #If optional parameter data is supplied/exists, add it as a new hash item
 if ($null -ne $OptionalParam1Data) {
      $MyParameters.Add('OptionalParam1', $OptionalParam1Data)
 }
```

You can repeat adding things with IF to the set of parameters all day.  If data exists then the parameter is added, if it doesn't then it's not.  The only gotcha is still the null parameters.  There has to be at least 1 real parameter from the get-go else the function can still complain, so you would need to catch that situation and handle it separately.

```
Example:     
Do-MyFunction @MyParameters
```